Linux kernel 6.1 start_kernel procedure
I'm learning about kernel boot. There's a thing that makes me confused. I got a PDF from the NXP community. It said that before the kernel starts, the code trapped into head-common.S to get the machine type and check the r2 register. That PDF is based on kernel 4.1.15. I read the code for kernel 6.1.75 and found that b start_kernel moved to head-common.S. Besides, head.S includes head-common.S.
I want to know: is head.S the first file to execute during kernel boot, considering that all other necessary work has been done by the BIOS and bootloader? Also, I want to know who decided to move start_kernel from head.S. I want to see some code.

The definition of start_kernel() has existed in init/main.c since at least kernel version 0.95:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/0.95/source/init/main.c#L129
(Pick the kernel version you want from the left sidebar, then type in start_kernel into the Search Identifier field to repeat the search on any kernel version known to the Elixir Cross Referencer.)
I don't think Git history reaches back that far, so I cannot easily check, but I would guess that the person who decided to put it there... was probably Linus Torvalds himself.
The PDFs from NXP are probably talking about the ARM architecture: if you are familiar with x86 assembler programming, there is no such thing as the r2 register on x86. (The first 8 general-purpose registers each have specific names firmly established in the history of the x86 architecture: see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/16,_32,_and_64_Bits )
Note that each processor architecture has its own version of head.S:
linux-6.12.4$ find . -name head.S

./arch/arc/kernel/head.S
./arch/csky/kernel/head.S
./arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S
./arch/arm/kernel/head.S
./arch/xtensa/kernel/head.S
./arch/microblaze/kernel/head.S
./arch/openrisc/kernel/head.S
./arch/arm64/kernel/head.S
./arch/riscv/kernel/head.S
./arch/x86/platform/pvh/head.S
./arch/parisc/boot/compressed/head.S
./arch/parisc/kernel/head.S
./arch/mips/boot/compressed/head.S
./arch/mips/kernel/head.S
./arch/loongarch/kernel/head.S
./arch/m68k/coldfire/head.S
./arch/m68k/68000/head.S
./arch/m68k/kernel/head.S
./arch/sh/boot/romimage/head.S
./arch/hexagon/kernel/head.S
./arch/nios2/boot/compressed/head.S
./arch/nios2/kernel/head.S
./arch/alpha/boot/head.S
./arch/alpha/kernel/head.S
./arch/s390/purgatory/head.S
./arch/s390/boot/head.S

But head-common.S exists for the ARM architecture only:
linux-6.12.4$ find . -name head-common.S

./arch/arm/kernel/head-common.S

For x86, the point where the kernel execution begins seems to be arch/x86/boot/header.S instead. More specifically, the classic BIOS main entry point seems to be the _start label, which contains a short jump to start_of_setup.
With (U)EFI, the execution starts at efi_pe_entry() instead, which can be found in drivers/firmware/efi/libstub/x86-stub.c for x86 hardware, and in drivers/firmware/efi/libstub/efi-stub-entry.c for other architectures using EFI (at least ARM, ARM64, RISC-V and LoongArch). However, the arch/x86/boot/header.S still defines the header structures which will be used to specify the address of the UEFI entry function on x86.
It seems to me that in modern Linux kernels, start_kernel() is generally the point where architecture- and platform-specific initialization ends and the common Linux code begins (with architecture-specific subroutines, inclusions and overrides wherever needed).

From your comments, I see you're probably interested in ARM, and the piece missing from your puzzle is probably the kernel image decompressor code: see https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.75/source/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S
It is in the beginning of the zImage file and is where the bootloader will jump to. It relocates (if necessary) and decompresses the rest of the kernel code. Once the decompressor is done, it jumps to the kernel startup entry point in arch/arm/kernel/head.S. Because the ARM architecture has a lot of variants and extensions, there are a lot of #ifdefs and parts of it have been clearly moved to head-common.S just to keep the mess manageable.
The head.S does CPU-specific initialization, that includes specifying where to continue after starting up the Memory Management Unit; at that point, the structure of the visible address space is transformed into the virtual view enforced by the MMU.
After the MMU is started up, execution continues at __mmap_switched in head_common.S. And then, after decompressing some data structures, we finally get to call start_kernel.

Thanks for your answer.

While 'the person' I menttioned is not a true man, What I really wang to know is, after bootloader did everything before kernel init, who told the kernel to start from head.S file? I want to see code about this issue, I'm trying to find it. Btw, I completed read code about dts mount in kernel, after using of ops to load dtb from rom, platform_device and platform_driver start to init? or they two start earlier than dtb load?

Please see my edit.
